# WPF ListView.Items.SortDescriptions Error

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting

I am using the WPF `SortDescriptions` sorting technique and I have found that it will not sort numbers. When given a column of numbers to sort it tells me that 
"Failed to Compare two elements in the array"

Does anyone know how to get around this? Or maybe give me some hints?
I noticed that it will only sort strings right, but not numbers. It throws an exception when given a number.

Here is my code thanks:

```
     private void SortClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          GridViewColumnHeader column = sender as GridViewColumnHeader;
          String field = column.Tag as String;

          if (_curSortCol != null)
          {
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(_curSortCol).Remove(_curAdorner);
           ListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();          
          }

          ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
          if (_curSortCol == column &&
                _curAdorner.Direction == newDir)
            newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;

          _curSortCol = column;
          _curAdorner = new SortAdorner(_curSortCol, newDir);
          AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(
              _curSortCol).Add(_curAdorner);

          //THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES!!

          ListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
              new SortDescription(field, newDir));
    }
```

Comment: what exception does it throw, have **you** made any process in tracking down this proble,?

Comment: I figured it out, I bounded my Property TO a custom made dataobject, and that dataobject did not have Icomparable implemented within in. So instead i made it into a String, which has Icomparable located inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement IComparable interface to your custom object.(!not IComparable< T >).

ex:

```
public class MyObject : IComparable
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        MyObject rhs = object as MyObject;
        if (rhs == null) return -1;
        return (Value - rhs.Value);
    }
}
```